Copy dot files only
In Zsh, to copy regular files only, I use
cp -a -- ~/dir1/* ~/dir2/

And to include dot files, I will add the D glob qualifier:
cp -a -- ~/dir1/*(D) ~/dir2/

But is there a glob qualifier to copy dot files only, without regular ones? (I know about cp -a -- ~/dir1/.* ~/dir2/, but I would prefer something more verstalite.)

What's not versatile about .*? Why would zsh add a glob qualifier for that?

From a terminology PoV, regular files generally means files with the S_IFREG bit in the st_mode field of their inode, that is, regular files as opposed to directories, symlinks, fifos, devices... Regardless of the names they may have in any directory they're linked to. You use the . qualifier to select regular files (cp -- *(.) /dest/ or cp -- *(-.) /dest/ for the check of file type to be done after symlink resolution).

@StéphaneChazelas "What's not versatile about .*? Why would zsh add a glob qualifier for that?" Sorry, probably I was too tired. It seems there is in fact nothing wrong with it.

If we're restricted to using just glob qualifiers, the only option is using (e) to execute arbitrary code to check the file names:
cp -a -- ~/dir1/*(De+'[[ ${REPLY:t} == .* ]]'+) ~/dir2


Hello. Sorry, but I'm looking for a glob qualifier, not just for an arbitrary solution. I know about the solution you have posted, but it has at least one drawback: dir1/ must contain 1+ dot files; otherwise, there will be an error.

@jsx97, yut23 is showing how to use the e glob qualifier for that. That's likely a tongue in cheek answer to a (IMO) silly question. Other than using e, you could do hidden() [[ $REPLY:t = .* ]] and use ~/dir1/*(D+hidden) (note that the hidden function doesn't consider /home/.me./dir1/.cache/file as hidden as it only looks for a leading . in the basename, change it to hidden() [[ $REPLY = (*/|).* ]] for that).
